# C# DLL (using 3F DLLExport for exporting functions) not debuggable in Delphi application

Tags: c#, delphi, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols, dllexport

I'm trying to export functions from a C# Class Library (.Net Framework 4.8) to later use it in a Delphi project.

**C# part:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport (CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void Init()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hallo von testprogramm c#");
        }
    }
}
```

The C# project is set to X86 only, and I used 3F/DLLExport:

[image: DllExport Setup Screen]

In Visual Studio, I enabled "Debug of native Code" in the Project Settings.

I compile in "Debug" Mode, therefore Debug symbols get generated (I see a `.pdb` file next to the DLL).

**Delphi part:**

```pascal
procedure TestDLL();
var
  dllHandle : THandle;
  dllInit: PInit;
begin
  dllHandle := SafeLoadLibrary('path\to\ClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll');
  dllInit := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'Init');
  dllInit();
end;
```

When I call the Delphi procedure, the DLL gets correctly attached and the `Init` function get called. The `MessageBox` appears on the screen.

**Problem**

When I attach Visual Studio to the running Delphi program, Visual Studio claims that there are no symbols loaded for the DLL, and therefore I'm not able to debug the C# code.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I did this sort of thing in the past and never had this kind of problem.

Comment: Got the correct pdb? I assume for this unmanaged export to work the assembly gets patched and therefore you need a pdb from after the patching process.

Comment: Are you sure VS is complaining about missing symbols for DLL. Perhaps it is complaining about missing symbols for Delphi application itself. I don't know what is the proper procedure for debugging DLL's in VS but in Delphi you configure your DLL project with information about host application that will be loading and using your DLL. Then Delphi IDE actually launches the host application and attaches to it so it can debug the DLL. Perhaps VS requires similar approach especially if Host Application is not written in same programming language

Comment: I have a .dll and a .pdb file in the output folder and also in the obj folder. In the output folder .dll there are the exported functions visible using `dumpbin /exports` and the both .pdb files differ from each other. So I assume that the .pdb file gets correctly patched.

Comment: @SilverWarior yes you can define the host application in Visual Studio. But you don't have to (you don't have to in Delphi either) you can simply start the host application by yourself and then attach Delphi / VS to the running process.

Comment: @White Does this work even if the host application is compiled with different programming language? By the way is your Delphi application compiled with Debug or Release mode?

Comment: Delphi is compiled with Debug.

Comment: @SilverWarior and yes the language of the host application doesn't matter for debugging the DLL. I debugged C# Dlls used in an Delphi Host application which used a Fortran DLL which internally used the C# DLL. Thats completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
In the .csproj of the C# Project I need to specifiy the PDB to Full

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
```

If you start the Host application through Visual Studio (Startprofile) check the checkbox mixed debugging. And specify the host application. Then you can debug into the DLL.
If you want to attach to an already running host application you need to specify the correct debugger type in the "Attach to process" window.
Default it is set to "automatic (native code)" this is in this case wrong as we don't want to debug native code. Manually selection "Managed (.Net 4.x)" is the solution.
[image: manually selection debugger type]